# Is good practice to create one generic service?

Tags: angular, coding-style, angular-services

I am new in Angular 2. I wonder what is good practice. I created a service where I had a method. Then, I saw that I can use generic service and propably I can use it in more cases. Below I present code from it.

```
getSpecific(): Promise<ResponseApi<MyModel>> {
    return this._http.get('api/specific')
        .map((response: Response) => <ResponseApi<MyModel>>response.json())
        .toPromise()
        .catch((error) => { throw (error) });
}

getGeneric<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map((response: Response) => <T>response.json())
        .toPromise()
        .catch((error) => { throw (error) });
}
```

What is good practise? Use different services or use one generic service like in this case. `ReponseApi` is my model where I have properties like `StatusCode` and `Result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you want to talk about good practice, you should

- Stop using promises, as Observables are way better
- Use the new `HttpClient`, as the old `Http` is being deprecated
- Handle your error instead of throwing it

Other than that, services are made to be reusable. I don't see why you should not have a common service. You can also make services that use this service.

For instance, this is usually what I do with firebase : one generic service that is being called by several specific services.

Comment: OTOH, once you realize that a service is generally not the right place to handle an error and that the new HttpClient parses the JSON automatically, your common service does nothing more than HttpClient. Services to get / post data are generally made specific to hide the specificities associated to the kind of data: what is the actual type returned, what is the actual type of data sent, how should the response be transformed if necessary, how should the request be transformed if necessary, what is the URL to use.

Comment: I would agree for generic errors, but since services are supposed to handle your business logic, nothing prevents you from handling your errors (specific to a feature) in your service; after your interceptor. But I agree with the uselessness of the service *in this case*, and the purpose of specific services.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it. My service is just HttpClient service and nothing else. So it is not bad practice that I make one generic service?

Comment: @KamLet personally I would say no, but as JB Nizet said, in this case your service isn't that useful. Are you sure you're using the new `HttpClient` ? `json`ing the response usually mean you are using the previous `Http` module